# jQuery textarea value just gives a "True", instead of value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Following code:
HTML-Form Textarea:

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="80" id="msg"></textarea><br>
```

jQuery sending the form:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "source/contact.php",
        data: "email=" + $("#email").val() + "&msg=" + $("#msg").val() + "&phone=" + nr,
        // Display Answer
        success: function(answer){
            alert(unescape(answer));
            $("#form_contact")[0].reset();
        },
        // If sending failed: Display error message
        error: function(){
            alert("Form Sending Fail!");
        }
    });
```

I also tried:

```
$("textarea#msg").val()
```

Then here point that out with php:

```
$msg = $_POST['msg'];
```

And it always gives TRUE back (displayed as "1")

What am I doing wrong??

EDIT: PHP-File:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['msg']) || !isset($_POST['phone'])){
    echo "Access denied!";
    exit;
}
$email = htmlentities($_POST['email']);
$msg = htmlentities($_POST['msg']);
$phone = htmlentities($_POST['phone']);

if($email != "" && $msg =! "" && $phone != ""){
    echo "Danke f%FCr ihre Anfrage! \n Email: $email \n Msg: $msg \n Phone: $phone";
}else{
    echo "Bitte alle Fleder ausf%FCllen!";
}
```

?>

Comment: What response does the `contact.php` give you, when you execute it?

Comment: Did you alert $("textarea#msg").val() or $("#msg").val() before sending with Ajax?

Comment: I added the PHP-Code...
no, I didnt... just checked if $("#msg").val() is not empty

Comment: In the last `if` statement fix this:  `$msg =!` to `$msg !=`

Comment: try in ajax `data:{ email: $("#email").val(),msg:$("#msg").val() },`

Comment: Thanks Deryck, that was the solution... again such a stupid Problem solved! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,the  **$msg !=**

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['msg']) || !isset($_POST['phone'])){
        echo "Access denied!";
        exit;
    }
    $email = htmlentities($_POST['email']);
    $msg = htmlentities($_POST['msg']);
    $phone = htmlentities($_POST['phone']);

    if($email != "" && $msg != "" && $phone != ""){
        echo "Danke f%FCr ihre Anfrage! \n Email: $email \n Msg: $msg \n Phone: $phone";
    }else{
        echo "Bitte alle Fleder ausf%FCllen!";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: That solution was already in the comments and I solved it with that. Anyway, thanks!